# Some basic UML questions

Tags: c#, oop, uml

What does it mean when you have something as the following picture?
[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/3876/3gmygrextht5dsd2c4svh1i.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/3876/3gmygrextht5dsd2c4svh1i.png)

Each Customer has none, one or more Orders while each Order has only one Customer?

And in relationship to the following one:
[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4372/bod24yjzahqjlnrvjtfezax.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4372/bod24yjzahqjlnrvjtfezax.png)

What does the black diamond mean in this context? How is that black diamond called?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first picture, an `Order` can only be associated to *one* `Customer`, while one `Customer` can have *many* `Order`'s.

The black diamond in the second example is called a [*composition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), or an associated relationship. Composition usually has a strong life cycle dependency between instances of the container class and instances of the contained class or classes. In your case `Order` is the container class and the `Customer` is its contained class.

Reference:

- [*Class diagram - Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram also describes some additional elements

Answer (score 2):

In the top diagram, the arrows indicate an association.  This means that a Customer can have many Orders, and an Order can have one Customer.  Since there is an arrowhead at each end, it means that the relationship is "bi-directional" meaning that each class has a reference to the other (each class "knows about" the other).

The corresponding classes might look like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public Customer Customer {get;set;}
    // Other order properties
}

public class Customer
{
    public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
    // Other Customer properties
}
```

In the second diagram, the filled diamond represents "Composition."  This is a more specific type of a relationship.  Composition is usually compared to "aggregation," which would be an open diamond.

With the filled diamond (composition), it means that an Order has a "strong life-cycle" dependency on the Customer class.  A common way of understanding Composition is saying that one class "owns" another.  In this case, you would say that the Order "owns" the Customer, which doesn't really make sense, so I think it might be a bad example.  Really, it's the Customer that should own the Order, so I think the filled diamond should be on the other side of the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [good site](http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/) to remember these

As Anthony says for the actual examples